# Word or expression meaning giving value to something that apparently doesn't

Tags: expressions, idioms, word-usage

I'm trying to find an expression that means seeing value in something (or someone) when no one else sees it.
The idea I'm trying to put into words is the fact of challenging the defects of something or someone and enhancing their qualities for what they are.

An example could be someone that is seen as ugly under the mainstream standards of beauty, and is therefore rejected, but has some amazing qualities inside.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Read up on [59 Organizations Fighting Food Loss and Waste](https://foodtank.com/news/2016/07/fighting-food-loss-and-waste/) to see what terms they use. Or just focus on [Hunger Action LA](http://www.hungeractionla.org/projects), which I believe is heavily into supporting the kind of "smartphone apps" you have in mind.

Comment: Like [repurposing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repurposing) something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's seeking suggestions for a business name / slogan.

Comment: Hi @FumbleFingers, I didn't know this could be seen as off-topic.
I'm just trying to find an expression that means bringing value to something that might be seen as worthless

Answer (score 1):

Based on your original question citing food that some throw away but others consider valuable, consider:

> **One man's trash is another man's treasure.**
>   Prov. Something that one person considers worthless may be considered valuable by someone else. Q: Why would anyone want to hang a picture like that on the wall? A: One man's trash is another man's treasure. A: Bob's uncle is always going through people's garbage, looking for old stuff. B: One man's trash is another man's treasure.
>   [- The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/One+man%27s+trash+is+another+man%27s+treasure)

If you're referring to different assessments of beauty, consider:

> **Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.**
>   Prov. Different people have different ideas about what is beautiful. Bob: I can't believe Ted bought that ugly old car. Fred: He loves it. Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. 
>   [- The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Beauty+is+in+the+eye+of+the+beholder)